# Ubuntu not selectable in boot menu

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot

Im trying to dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10. i created a partition in windows 7, booted the Ubuntu cd, installed Ubuntu and created a swap space(following all instructions detailed in various video tutorials). after restarting and taking out the disk my computer boots directly into windows. also, in the boot menu where you select what os to boot, Ubuntu doesn't show up, just windows 7.  i didn't want to screw around with any settings and figured the community could figure out my problem faster than i could :p

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting you didn't install grub correctly. If your main hard disk is /dev/sda and Ubuntu is installed on say /dev/sda3, you should have installed it on the MBR of /dev/sda.

I suggest you boot from your Ubuntu disc, install boot-repair (sudo apt-get install boot-repair) and let it repair your bootloader.

Comment: thanks for the help and quick reply!

i found this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for anybody having similar problems. everything seems to be working as it should now, thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad this solved your problem. If this answer helped you, why don't you mark it as the correct one as a help for others?